# Question about $p \implies q$ predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$T$: a set of natural numbers.

$S_1$: $2$ is the only prime number that divides elements of $T$.
$S_2: T = \{16, 8, 528\}.$

I'm trying to figure out which statements imply each other, i.e., does $S_1$ imply $S_2$ and vice versa.

I'm not sure if $S_1 \implies S_2$, because $S_1$ doesn't seem to be necessary for $S_2$ to exist. 
But for $S_2 \implies S_1$, I think it is necessary that $2$ is the only prime that can divide $T$'s elements.

What do you guys think?  Cheers in advance, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to show that $S_1$ does **not** imply $S_2$, you should give an example of a situation (that is, a set $T$) for which $S_1$ is true, but $S_2$ is false.  Can you think of any?

Note that $S_2$ **does not** imply $S_1$ (assuming I am interpreting $S_1$ correctly).  In particular, $528$ is divisible by $3$, which is a prime number not equal to $2$.

Comment: $528$ definitely is not a power of $2$.

Comment: @Lord_Farin good catch.  Fixed it now.

Comment: I didn't even notice that. Great input! Thanks @ Lord_Farin, Omnomnomnom